# Создать пользователя

Tags: bash

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста, целый день мучаюсь.

Есть директория сайта. Нужно в скрипте создать пользователя для доступа по FTP к этой папочке. 
То есть, создать юзера+пароль и "запереть" его в директории с сайтом, запретив выполнение ssh.

Операционка debian, ftp сервер vsftpd

update:

На всякий случай дополню вопрос тем, что на текущий момент написано

```
#!/bin/bash

# Функция генерирует случайный пароль
function get_pass(){
 MATRIX="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
 LENGTH="8"
 while [ "${n:=1}" -le "$LENGTH" ]
 do
  PASS="$PASS${MATRIX:$(($RANDOM%${#MATRIX})):1}"
  let n+=1
 done
 }

# Сохраняем в переменные параметры запуска скрипта
DOMAIN=$1
USERNAME=$2

# Проверяем на равенство нулю введённый домен
if [ ! -n "$DOMAIN" ]; then
 echo -en "\033[0;31m"
 echo "Вы не указали имя домена, выполнение прервано!"
 tput sgr0
 exit 1
fi

# Проверяем на равенство нулю имя пользователя
if [ ! -n "$USERNAME" ]; then
 echo -en "\033[0;31m"
 echo "Вы не указали имя пользователя, выполнение прервано!"
 tput sgr0
 exit 1
fi

# Проверяем существование домена на сервере
if [ -e /etc/apache2/sites-available/$DOMAIN ]; then
 echo -en "\033[0;31m"
 echo "Домен $DOMAIN уже существует!"
 tput sgr0
 exit 1
fi

# Проверим, существует ли папка под этот домен
if [ -d /home/www/$DOMAIN ]; then
 echo -en "\033[0;31m"
 echo "Ошибка! Директория сайта $DOMAIN уже существует, выполнение прервано!"
 tput sgr0
 exit 1
fi

# Проверяем существование пользователя с таким именем
grep "^$USERNAME:" /etc/passwd >/dev/null
if ! [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
 echo -en "\033[0;31m"
 echo "Пользователь $USERNAME найден, выполнение прервано!"
 tput sgr0
 exit 1
fi

# Генерируем случайный пароль для пользователя
get_pass
PASSWORD=$PASS

# Случайный пароль для новой базы данных
get_pass
PASSWORD_OF_MYSQL=$PASS

echo "Домен:        $DOMAIN";
echo "Пользователь: $USERNAME";
echo "Пароль:       $PASSWORD";
```

Comment: @e-gragor, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @void, это не учебное задание, а практическое, у меня, к сожалению, профессия далека от этих дел. Давайте я вам покажу, что уже написал? А момент, на котором я завис - в вопросе(

Comment: @void, дополнил вопрос кодом. Дальше мучаюсь с функцией adduser

Comment: useradd --help

Comment: @eicto ну вы бы ещё ссылку на гугль дали. Я, допустим, не понимаю, как одной командой создать пользователя и пароль. Там в хелпе указано, что пароль нужно шифрованный указывать. А как его для этого зашифровать - непонятно. Как запереть пользователя в директории - тоже не понимаю. 

Чем издеваться, могли бы и практически помочь

Comment: Вот сейчас - большое спасибо, за статью и подробное объяснение  :)

А что означает зашифрованный пароль в качестве параметра? Как его зашифровать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как запереть пользователя в директории - тоже не понимаю.

это называется chroot и его правильная организация отдельная наука.

я вам говорю - useradd вместо adduser, useradd предназначен для скриптов. а если вы не можете [прочитать русский --help](http://pastebin.com/REfavZPM) то вряд-ли кто нить вам сможет помочь.